# add timepicker to bootstrap 4 input field form

Tags: bootstrap-4, timepicker

I am stuck on how to add a timepicker to a input field on a Bootstrap 4 admin template I am using.

I did have a Jquery one integrated and that worked before using the new admin Bootstrap 4 admin template, but now it don't work and think it is conflicting with some other Bootstrap Javascript files so seeing if can use a Bootstrap 4 timepicker, but I can't get one working, has anyone got any sample coding of one working in Bootstrap 4 form please.

Answer (score 6):

I do not understand your question completely, but I think this is what you are looking for:

https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/

Tempus Dominus is a jQuery datetime-picker plugin for Bootstrap 4. It requires minimum code to set up. **After importing the library**, all you have to write is:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'LT'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

See their [documentation](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/) for more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it working following your coding and importing the library from the link but it displays when clicking on the clock icon but it also displays the datepicker where as I just need the timepicker to show

Comment: I noticed the format: 'LT' part should just make it so the timepicker only shows but for some reason I am getting the datepicker show as well

Comment: Think I have done it, I removed the line     <script src="https://www.it-doneright.co.uk/admin/js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> and seems ok now

Comment: Can you please paste a complete HTML here so we don't have to go to external sites (ideally using CDNs)? thx.